# Universal Link not launching within app through url_launcher

Tags: flutter

- url_launcher: 5.7.10
- uni_links: 0.4.0

I'm trying to use url_launcher with uni_links.  I am able to successfully launch my app with:

```
xcrun simctl openurl booted https://my.domain.com/somewhere
```

However, if I have a button in my app with an onclick handler:

```
final url = "https://my.domain.com/somewhere";
final success = await launch(url, forceSafariVC: false, universalLinksOnly: true);
```

`success` is false and the app did not navigate properly

I've tried unsuccessfully:

```
  <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
  <array>
    <string>https</string>
  </array>
```

Answer (score 0):

The missing link here was updating the bundle ID to enable associated domains.  I had assumed since I was running locally in development I didn't need that step yet, but I was wrong.